# The synchronized keyword and race conditions produced unexpected error in java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm just starting the basics of threading in java.The synchronized keyword tells the scheduler not to context switch while in the middle of a thread execution. Also, race condition happens when more a thread tries to access the same resource. With that in mind, I created a simple class to demonstrate the concept to myself.

```
public class DemoThread{

    int i = 1;

    public void runThreads() {

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable () {
            @Override 
            public void run() {
                synchronized(this) {
                    i++;
                    System.out.println("Thread 1: " + i);
                }
            }
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                synchronized(this) {
                    i--;
                    System.out.println("Thread 2: " + i);
                }
            }
        });

        for (int k = 0; k <=100; k++) {
            t1.start();
            t2.start();
        }
    }
}
```

I simply have a forloop at the bottom to execute these threads 100 times. However, I get this error in the console:

```
Thread 2: 1Exception in thread "main" 
Thread 1: 1
java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:795)
    at thread_demo.DemoThread.runThreads(DemoThread.java:31)
    at thread_demo.main.main(main.java:9)
```

Why is that?

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with the synchronized keyword. You should consider removing it from the title.

Comment: "to execute these threads 100 times" if this code worked, it would execute them 101 times.

Answer (score 2):

The `start()` method in the `Thread` class has the following lines:

```
 if (threadStatus != 0)
            throw new IllegalThreadStateException();
```

The `threadStatus` is used to signalize the status of the given `Thread`. If it's 0 it means that the `Thread` has not yet been started. The code above means that, if You will try to invoke `start()` on the `Thread` that is already running - the `IllegalThreadStateException` will be thrown.

The specific error occurs because You are calling `start()` method more than once for the given threads both `t1` and `t2`

Comment: you mean I'm starting from t1, t2 more than once?

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
        for (int k = 0; k <=100; k++) {
            t1.start();
            t2.start();
        }
```

starts `t1` and `t2` more than once. It is prohibited.

Answer (score 1):

You can't start the same thread multiple times.
[Example](https://tio.run/##XY2xDoIwGIRn@xQXpjYEIqtE34AJN@PwC0SLUAj9wRjDs9cSO3nb3eW7a2mhpK2fzlUdWYuCtPkIAS/LxLqCNgyNI/b5Lx7nW@fj0C6DrtF7SJY8aXO/XEkhDGw6P6aGanDmF0zzCl5KheSE8m256dNh5nT0MHdGRgHIDogQI461UrnYcZb6w4nlv9k@VrE69wU)